# Numpy and Generator code has lower performance than naive append approach. How to improve?

Tags: python, performance, numpy, generator

I have written a `random_walk` simulation using `numpy` to allocate the data and Generators to execute the simulation steps. This `random_walk` is just a MWE from original code (that is not related at all with random walks but is a stochastic mathematical model too large and complex to use as an example. Nevertheless the `random_walk` MWE simulates the core components.

The reason I'm using generators is related to the simulation. I will run the simulation for a infinite time and I only dump the data in some corner cases. I can measure the probability of corner cases occurs hence I'm able to allocate the numpy array beforehand with high degree of precision (never mised), but that is a upper bound, hence I need to count how many times the corner cases occurred then slice the dataset (tha is "emulated" in the simulation).

For sake of comparison I have also written a similar naive approach using plain `append` to lists to store simulation data where I append only when corner cases occurs.

It's important to know that corner cases will occurs a billion times (will take a huge part of memory), but the final simulation will run for "infinite time" that is a VERY large number of steps. The corner cases are like 1e-10 prob to occurs.

And the final code has a stop condition that I emulated here using `distance` and the classical `simulation time`.

To my surprise, I noticed that `append` approach has a better performance than `numpy+generators`. As we can see in outputs below

For small datasets:

```
%timeit random_walk_naive(max_distance=1e5, simul_time=1e4)
5.35 ms ± 190 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit random_walk_simul(max_distance=1e5, simul_time=1e4)
16.3 ms ± 567 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

For larger datasets

```
%timeit random_walk_naive(max_distance=1e12, simul_time=1e7)
12.2 s ± 760 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit random_walk_simul(max_distance=1e12, simul_time=1e7)
36 s ± 102 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Running `cProfile` over the calls, I noticed the generator calls has similar execution time as the naive approach and all additional time was spent in `random_walk_simul` it self. Evaluating the `np.empty` and the slicing operation I noticed that time to create the empty dataset and slice it in return is minimal. Not contributing at all with the time spent in operations. Besides that the code is almost the same, except that in `generator` approach I first allocate the data to local variables then "flush" them to `numpy.array`, that was shown faster than flush directly, since I will use the values in `while` loop to evaluate the stop condition.

I need to understand why this behavior is showing up and if is expected; if don't how to fix it?

The full source code is pasted below

```
import numpy as np
from random import random

def clip(value, lower, upper):
    return lower if value < lower else upper if value > upper else value


def random_walk(s_0, a_0, pa, pb):
    """Initial position (often 0), acceleration, 0 < pa < pb < 1"""
    # Time, x-position, Velocity, Acceleration
    t, x, v, a = 0, s_0, 0, a_0
    yield (t, x, v, a)

    while True:        
        # Roll the dices
        god_wishes = random()

        if god_wishes <= pa:
                # Increase acceleration
                a += .005
        elif god_wishes <= pb:
                # Reduce acceleration
                a -= .005

        # Lets avoid too much acceleration
        a = clip(a, -.2, .2)

        # How much time has passed, since last update?
        dt = random()
        v += dt*a
        x += dt*v
        t += dt

        yield (t, x, v, a)


def random_walk_simul(initial_position = 0, acceleration = 0, 
                      prob_increase=0.005, prob_decrease=0.005, 
                      max_distance=10000, simul_time=1000):
    """Runs a random walk simulation given parameters

    Particle initial state (initial position and acceleration)
    State change probability (prob_increase, prob_decrease)
    Stop criteria (max_distance, simul_time)

    Returns a random_walk particle data
    """
    assert (0 < prob_increase+prob_decrease < 1), "Total probability should be in range [0, 1]"

    rw = random_walk(initial_position, acceleration, prob_increase, prob_decrease+prob_increase)

    # Over estimated given by law of large numbers expected value of a
    # uniform distribution
    estimated_N = int(simul_time * 2.2)

    data = np.empty((estimated_N, 4))

    # Runs the first iteraction
    n = 0
    (t, x, v, a) = rw.__next__()
    data[n] = (t, x, v, a)

    # While there is simulation time or not too far away
    while (t < simul_time) and (np.abs(x) < max_distance):
        n += 1
        (t, x, v, a) = rw.__next__()
        data[n] = (t, x, v, a)

    return data[:n]


def random_walk_naive(initial_position = 0, acceleration = 0, 
                      prob_increase=0.005, prob_decrease=0.005, 
                      max_distance=10000, simul_time=1000):
    """Emulates same behavior as random_walk_simul, but use append instead numpy and generators"""
    T = []
    X = []
    V = []
    A = []

    T.append(0)
    X.append(initial_position)
    V.append(0)
    A.append(acceleration)

    a = A[-1]
    t = T[-1]
    v = V[-1]
    x = X[-1]

    while (T[-1] < simul_time) and (abs(X[-1]) < max_distance):       
        god_wishes = random()
        if god_wishes <= prob_increase:
            # Increase acceleration
            a += .005
        elif god_wishes <= prob_increase+prob_decrease:
            # Reduce acceleration
            a -= .005

        # Lets avoid too much acceleration
        a = clip(a, -.2, .2)

        dt = random()
        t += dt
        v += dt*a
        x += dt*v

        # Storing next simulation step
        T.append(t)
        X.append(x)
        V.append(v)
        A.append(a)

    return np.array((T, X, V, A)).transpose()


def main():
    random_walk_naive(max_distance=1e9, simul_time=1e6)
    random_walk_simul(max_distance=1e9, simul_time=1e6)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Numpy has often slower performance for *scalars*. The efficiency boost that numpy can provide is when you do processing in *bulk*. So for example add a value to all elements of a 100x100 matrix. Not adding a value with `for` loops for example.

Comment: Because numpy is not meant to be used that way.

Comment: that was fast! Hence the best of two worlds should be: use naive approach calling the generators and dump the final data as a numpy array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be a good situation for using [numba](http://numba.pydata.org/):

```py
import numpy as np
from random import random
from numba import njit

# Baseline
%timeit random_walk_naive(max_distance=1e9, simul_time=1e6)
1.28 s ± 277 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

# Few adjustments for numba

@njit
def random_walk_numba(initial_position = 0, acceleration = 0, 
                      prob_increase=0.005, prob_decrease=0.005, 
                      max_distance=10000, simul_time=1000):

    T, X, V, A = [0], [initial_position], [0], [acceleration]

    t, x, v, a = T[-1], X[-1], V[-1], A[-1]

    while (T[-1] < simul_time) and (abs(X[-1]) < max_distance):       
        god_wishes = random()
        if god_wishes <= prob_increase:
            # Increase acceleration
            a += .005
        elif god_wishes <= prob_increase+prob_decrease:
            # Reduce acceleration
            a -= .005

        # Lets avoid too much acceleration
        lower, upper = -0.2, 0.2
        
        a = lower if a < lower else upper if a > upper else a
        
        dt = random()
        t += dt
        v += dt*a
        x += dt*v

        # Storing next simulation step
        T.append(t)
        X.append(x)
        V.append(v)
        A.append(a)
            
    return np.array((T, X, V, A)).transpose()

%timeit random_walk_numba(max_distance=1e9, simul_time=1e6)
172 ms ± 32.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Notice that you cannot call `clip` but luckily that is easy to re-implement inside.

Comment: Why clip cannot be called?

Comment: Functions called by @jit/@njit decorated functions also need to be @jit/@njit decorated.